# session_destroy() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How come destroy_session() method doesn't work.

After set_session(), destroy_session(), I still can read_session().

```
function set_session() {
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_userdata('id', 4);
}

function destroy_session() {
    session_start(); 
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}

function read_session() {
    $this->load->library('session');

    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The Codeigniter session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.

to unset a session variable:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('variable');
```

to destroy the whole session:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

hope this helps. ref: [codeigniter doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: I think CI3 now uses PHP's native sessions.

Comment: I found the reason is i didn't load the session library. sorry.
I read the user guide, in CI 3.0, we can use either session_destroy() or
$this->session->sess_destroy()